# Input to reshape is a tensor with *** values, but the requested shape has ***

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use output of embedding layer to be the kernel of a convolutional calculator, here is my code:

```
length_peptide = 20
length_pmhc = 34
num_aa = 22
embedding_dim = 128
input_peptide = keras.Input(shape=(length_peptide,))
input_pmhc = keras.Input(shape=(length_pmhc,))
shared_embedding = layers.Embedding(num_aa,embedding_dim)

class Kernel_pmhc(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__()
    
    def build(self,inputs):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(9,34),
            initializer = "random_normal",
            trainable=True
        )
    def call(self,inputs):
        return tf.matmul(self.w,inputs)

kernel_pmhc_1 = Kernel_pmhc(name="test1")
kernel_pmhc_2 = Kernel_pmhc(name="test2")
kernel_pmhc_3 = Kernel_pmhc(name="test3")
kernel_pmhc_4 = Kernel_pmhc(name="test4")


my_weight = tf.stack(
    [kernel_pmhc_1(inputs=shared_embedding(input_pmhc)),
     kernel_pmhc_2(inputs=shared_embedding(input_pmhc)),
     kernel_pmhc_3(inputs=shared_embedding(input_pmhc)),
     kernel_pmhc_4(inputs=shared_embedding(input_pmhc))],axis=-1)
my_weight = tf.reshape(tensor=my_weight,shape=(9,embedding_dim,1,4))

x = shared_embedding(input_peptide)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.expand_dims(x,3)
x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, my_weight, strides=(1, 1), padding="VALID")
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(units=128,activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
affinity = layers.Dense(units=1,activation="softmax")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_peptide,input_pmhc], outputs=affinity)
```

when fitting the model, here is the error:

```
Input to reshape is a tensor with 1088 values, but the requested shape has 34
```

any idea to fix the code or any other method to use output of layers as kernel

I have change the code

```
my_weight = tf.reshape(tensor=my_weight,shape=(9,embedding_dim,1,4))
```

to

```
my_weight = tf.expand_dims(kernel_pmhc_1(inputs=shared_embedding(input_pmhc)),-1)
```

it did not work.